# FHIR Rersources for Specialty

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to know what FHIR resource has to be used for bringing the list of specialities that are available for an organisation. These specialities are encounter specific so the response must be returned along with its encounter information based on the organisation.

Is that advisable to use List resource in FHIR?

Answer (score 0):

If you [search](http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/http.html#search) a FHIR server for a 'collection' of resources (like Encounter, HealthcareService or any other) the standard response would be a [Bundle](http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/bundle.html) rather than a List.